# Opening Arabic-named files in Android

Tags: android, file-io, arabic, filenotfoundexception

I am getting a FileNotFoundException when trying to open Arabic-named files in Android even though the files are there. Is it possible to open Arabic-named files on Android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code! what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to create a File object using new File(String path)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that is not possible to open files with Arabic names in Android since that Arabic input has limited support in Android. For best practice always Latin letters with no special symbols.

I know this answer is kind of late, but it might help someone else solve his problem.